# Post to application wall as application not as user

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I created an **asp.net mvc 3** facebook application using facebook c# sdk.

I'm trying to **post to my application wall**, it works, but the post is created in this format:

**[my account name] via [my application]**

So, the post appears in the **[my application] + others** group.

I want the post appears as **made by the application, not made by me**, so the post appears in the **just [my application]** group.

I was looking for answers for this problem, and everybody says, you have to get the access token for application, but nobody says how to do that.

Please could anyone provide an example code of how to do that???

---

I tried both ways (three really) but all the three gave me the following error:

The entity (class EntApplication) backed by id 204182346262383 cannot be seen by the current viewer 204182346262383 (EntID: 204182346262383).

Here is my code:

```
    private void Publish(string message, string caption, string description, string name, string picture, string link)
    {
        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["message"] = message;
        args["caption"] = caption;
        args["description"] = description;
        args["name"] = name;
        args["picture"] = picture;
        args["link"] = link;

        string path = AppId + "/feed";
        var fbApp = new FacebookClient(GetAppAccessToken());
        fbApp.Post(path, args);
    }

    private string GetAppAccessToken()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookOAuthClient { ClientId = AppId, ClientSecret = SecretKey };
        dynamic result = fb.GetApplicationAccessToken();
        var appAccessToken = result.access_token;
        return appAccessToken.ToString();
    }
```

I really appreciate help with this, I'm stucked with this for many days. I always get to a dead end.

Comment: I have an exception (OAuthException) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
How did you give permissions to application post on your page? I can give permissions to user, but not for page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make the request using facebook application access token.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("{app_access_token}");
dynamic result = fb.Post("/{app_id}/feed", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "message", "hello" } });
```

There are two ways you can use the application token.

1. Using FacebookOAuthClient: (This method gets the application access token using the OAuth2 standards which is the preferable way to get the app access token. but makes a request to the facebook server.)

   ```
   var fb = new FacebookOAuthClient { ClientId = "{app_id}", ClientSecret = "{app_secret}" };
   dynamic result = fb.GetApplicationAccessToken();
   var appAccessToken = result.access_token;
   ```
2. Manually creating the application token:

   ```
   var appAccessToken = "{app_id}|{app_secret}";
   ```

Replace {app_id} and {app_secret} with appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

As *prabir* suggested you need to use a facebook client authenticated as the application and not the connected user.

Here is a short code snipet using version 5.03 beta:

```
var fbApp = new FacebookClient(FacebookContext.Current);
dynamic result = fbApp.Post("/"+FacebookContext.Current.AppId+"/feed", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "message", "Hello World" } });
```