# Getting FB accesstoken from graph API by AppID+Appsecret

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since i cant use facebook c# sdk on my server, i would like to know how to obtain my apps accesstoken. I suppose i need to use the graph api? I never developed on facebook before, so some help on where to start would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053490/post-to-application-wall-as-application-not-as-user/5058700#5058700) you can get the application access token like this:

```
var appAccessToken = "app_id|app_secret";
```

Comment: You don't need the SDK for this, just take your app id and your app secret and place the vertical bar character in between.